# visual studio 2017 web deploy emply database connection strings

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2017

I have a C# app that was initially written in VS2015 but earlier this year we upgraded to 2017.  I opened the project in VS2017 months ago and kept going.  There is a long story that I don't think is relevant here about some serious weirdness that happened to that app related to `css` and `js` deployment in the last 4-5 business days.  Suffice it to say that I threw up my hands and created a new c#/.net framework project in VS2017 and copied the main source files and the web.config file over; re-made my models; brought in the necessary nuget packages, etc.  I built the project without issue.

I am now trying to do a Web Deploy.  This should be a simple thing.  the "release" version of the project needs to have the relevant files transferred to an IIS dev server.  I did this many, many times with VS2017 before the weirdness.  It worked.

Now, with a .Net Framework project created from scratch in VS2017 Web Deploy fails with the error

```
The 'Connection String' argument cannot be null or empty.
```

This is peculiar since when I created the Deploy profile I told it not to deploy databases.  It appears, however, that unchecking the "Use this connection string at runtime" boxes in the Web Deply settings is ignored.  Unchecking the boxes and saving the edits then re-editing the settings shows the boxes checked.  Unchecking, saving, exiting VS and re-entering has the boxes checked.

I see the connection elements in the `Release.pubxml` file generated

```
    <Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
      <PropertyGroup>
        ...
        <PublishDatabaseSettings>
          <Objects xmlns="">
            <ObjectGroup Name="MsSQLEntities" Order="1" Enabled="False">
              <Destination Path="" />
              <Object Type="DbCodeFirst">
                <Source Path="DBContext" DbContext="myapp.Models.MsSQLEntities, My App" Origin="Configuration" />
              </Object>
            </ObjectGroup>
            <ObjectGroup Name="MySQLEntities" Order="2" Enabled="False">
              <Destination Path="" />
              <Object Type="DbCodeFirst">
                <Source Path="DBContext" DbContext="myapp.Models.MySQLEntities, My App" Origin="Configuration" />
              </Object>
            </ObjectGroup>
          </Objects>
        </PublishDatabaseSettings>
      </PropertyGroup>
      <ItemGroup>
        <MSDeployParameterValue Include="MySQLEntities-Web.config Connection String">
          <UpdateDestWebConfig>False</UpdateDestWebConfig>
        </MSDeployParameterValue>
        <MSDeployParameterValue Include="MsSQLEntities-Web.config Connection String">
          <UpdateDestWebConfig>False</UpdateDestWebConfig>
        </MSDeployParameterValue>
      </ItemGroup>
    </Project>
```

I have looked at the `Release.pubxml` file from an earlier copy that was made of this project.  It would have been made bt vs2015.  Eventhough I *know* that I unchecked the DB connection boxes above; this file has full connection strings in it.

I have now tried copying the "old" pubxml file to the new project but nothing changes.

Oh, just noticed in the pubxml file above it talks about "DbCodeFirst".  I am pretty sure this was all DB first.

Help?

**EDIT**

sorry, somehow duplicated a section in the original

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue.  Something in the way the MySQL libs set themselves up puts a lot of bogus chaff in the web.config file.  All the entries mention `connectionStringName="LocalMySqlServer"`.  I commented out all those blocks and it's working again.

Also, even though web publish threw up a popup to tell me it had failed, it really hadn't.  It actually published to the remote dev site.  Running the app over there dumped enough error hints to find the info above.